# Force ADO (not ADO NET) to use older DLLs from app dir

Tags: ado

I have a problem after the last Windows update. Same as on:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/windows-10-update-kb4015217-windows-7-update/d6ee5ee8-a362-48fd-be1d-26a6b6526c34 (my application uses ADO, not ADO NET).

Is it possible to force ADO to use older DLLs from app dir. I have put the following files in my app dir:

- msado15.dll,
- msadomd.dll,
- msadox.dll,
- oledb32.dll.

And a redirection file

- Project1.exe.Local

My test application is called Project1.exe.

I did not solve the problem. Does redirection work with ActiveX components (like ADO)? Maybe I should add other files?